# How to make normal subgroup sign in overleaf?

Tags: symbols, amsmath, overleaf

Overleaf is saying that both `\unlhd` and `\trianglelefteq` are undefined control commands, although `\traingleleft` works fine.

How else can I make normal subgroup symbol i.e. [image]

with an equality sign below.

Comment: I don't know how overleaf actually works, but you might have to load the `amssymb` package.

Answer (score 3):

You need the `amssymb` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$H \unlhd G$
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Or even without the package you could say:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{AMSa}{U}{msa}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Bhaskarunlhd}{\mathrel}{AMSa}{"45}

\begin{document}
$H \Bhaskarunlhd G$
\end{document}
```

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth, you're welcome, but note that the usual way of say thanks in this site is upvote any good answer (of any question) and [accept the best answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer) (only one) to your own question.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware of stack rules sir, but I was first trying it, I guess I am too dud with tex to actually use your help, or overleaf doesnot accept ams package. It didnt work. thanks anyways

Comment: Oh, ok. Overleaf seems to be a nasty little thing...

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth, I added a package indipendent solution.

Comment: Jjust copying it inside `\(\)` is giving many errors. I am not sure I am doing it right, acn you try it in a blank page in overleaf.com and see how can I make it work. If you are not busy, thanks. Otherwise I will just use the one without equal sign, not a problem

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth, works fine for me. Did you go to source mode and pasted seperately what belongs to my examples preamble into overleafs preamble (preamble := "everything that comes before `\begin{document}`") and the instruction itself, i.e. `$H \Bhaskarunlhd G$` or `\(H \Bhaskarunlhd G\)` where you want it to be in the text body, which means somewhere in between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`?

Comment: yeah thanks very much ruben. Can you do me a favour and edit your answer to explain how to add other such symbols which overleaf isnt accepting, like `\nmid` and `\blacksquare` also it says \mathbb is unvalid control sequence. How to declare symbolfont and declaremathsymbol, for various fonts is there a list ?